# can't compile st build

Tags: linux, terminal, git, st-terminal

i was trying to download someone's st build from github [here](https://github.com/LukeSmithxyz/st) and when i run `make` or `sudo make install`
it gives me the following error

```
st build options:
/bin/sh: 1: pkg-config: not found
/bin/sh: 1: pkg-config: not found
CFLAGS  = -I/usr/X11R6/include     -DVERSION="0.8.1" -D_XOPEN_SOURCE=600 -O
/bin/sh: 1: pkg-config: not found
/bin/sh: 1: pkg-config: not found
LDFLAGS = -L/usr/X11R6/lib -lm -lrt -lX11 -lutil -lXft -lXrender
CC      = c99
c99 -I/usr/X11R6/include  `pkg-config --cflags fontconfig`  `pkg-config --cflags freetype2` -DVERSION=\"0.8.1\" -D_XOPEN_SOURCE=600 -O -c x.c
/bin/sh: 1: pkg-config: not found
/bin/sh: 1: pkg-config: not found
In file included from x.c:15:
/usr/include/X11/Xft/Xft.h:39:10: fatal error: ft2build.h: No such file or directory
 #include <ft2build.h>
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make: *** [Makefile:22: x.o] Error 1
```

is there something i should download?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you should download `pkg-config`. It's available in most distributions, either as the original "pkg-config" or the alternative "pkgconf".